# docker-compose down can't stop all containers

Tags: docker-compose

I start `docker-compose` this way: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up` and when I execute `docker-compose down --remove-orphans` only containers described in `docker-compose.yml` affected. How to kill them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `-f` flag in the `docker-compose down` command again.

Have you tried: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml down --remove-orphans`?

Side Note:

- If this is one docker-compose setup, I would recommend to use one compose file.
- You can always fall back to executing multiple commands: `docker-compose down --remove-orphans && docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down --remove-orphans`

Comment: i tryed, `docker-compose down -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml --remove-orphans` and got error, tnx